# How can I securely pass an arbitrarily deep path to a webapp (Flask, in this case)?

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, werkzeug

I have a form that sends a string to my Flask app when the form is posted. The string is a filepath, so I'd like to make sure it doesn't contain anything nasty, like `../../../etc/passwd`. Werkzeug, which Flask uses, has a handy function called `secure_filename` that strips nasty stuff out of filenames. Unfortunately, when fed a full path like `templates/example.html`, it converts the `/` to `_`, so we end up with `templates_example.html`.

It seems sensible, then, to split the path up into levels, so I send `templates` and `example.html` separately and then join them together again on the server. This works great, except that the path can be arbitrarily deep. I could just string together `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` and hope that nobody every goes deeper than `dir4`, but that seems dumb.

What's the right way to handle validation of paths of unknown depth? Validate differently? Send the data differently? Encode the path differently, then decode it on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [werkzeug.routing.PathConverter](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.PathConverter) to handle arbitrary paths like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/arbitrary/<path:my_path>")
def arbitrary_path(my_path):
    return my_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

With the oversimplified sample above you can see that if you visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/arbitrary/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` it will return `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` and if you visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/arbitrary/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/dir9/dir10` it will return `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/dir9/dir10`

Comment: That's your browser resolving the path.  By itself the path converter does not sanitize the path.  See my answer below for the proper solution for that problem.

Comment: I agree with Armin. Relying on `<path:...>` to secure a file path is not enough and is a big security hole.

Answer (score 11):

For situations like this Flask has `safe_join` which raises 404 if a user attempts to leave the path:

```
>>> safe_join('/foo/bar', 'test')
'/foo/bar/test'
>>> safe_join('/foo/bar', 'test/../other_test')
'/foo/bar/other_test'
>>> safe_join('/foo/bar', 'test/../../../etc/htpassw')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mitsuhiko/Development/flask/flask/helpers.py", line 432, in safe_join
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404: Not Found
```

Comment: I looked at `safe_join`, but I didn't think it would work like this. This is the line in `safe_join` doing the filtering of `../`, right? https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/security.py#L139 How does it pull the `../` out of the middle of the string?